# Using local imports in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have never really fully understood how packages are handled in Python and I'm having a problem with that right now. But googling doesn't seem to help as I find the topic really confusing.

I have a project with this structure:

```
project_name/
    src/
        main.py
        utils/
            string_utils.py
    tests/
        test_string_utils.py
```

I am using Pytest for running unit testing and currently inside the  "test_string_utils.py" file I have the following:

```
from ..src.utils.string_utils import StringUtilsClass
```

But I go to the folder "project_name" and try to run tests with any of this command I get errors:

```
$ pytest tests/
```

ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package

I know about the -m argument for python, but it seems that  running "pytest -m" has a completely different behavior.

How can I solve this? Am I using the wrong folder architecture? I don't think what I'm building should be a pip package (which would simplify imports)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try : `from src.utils.string_utils import StringUtilsClass` without .. before src?
or `from string_utils import StringUtilsClass`

Comment: from src.utils.string_utils import StringUtilsClas works. How is that?  is pytest loading the "src" module by itself?

Comment: "When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on sys.path looking for the package subdirectory." https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html