# python 3.6 unable to resolve import if module is executed from another folder

Tags: python, import, directory

I have folder and code structure like this

```
root folder
|
|---core folder
|     |
|     |----transaction.py
|     |            
|     |----executetransaction.py       
|
|---test folder
      |
      |----test_execute_transaction.py
```

transaction.py

```
class Transaction:
    def __init__(self,json):
        print("in create object")
```

executetransaction.py

```
from transaction import Transaction

def execute_transaction(json):
    trsobj = Transaction(json)
```

test_execute_transaction.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../")

from core import executetransaction
executetransaction.execute_transaction({"a":"b"})
```

when I execute `test_execute_transaction`, it is able to `import executetransaction` from core folder but I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transaction'` on the import code line in `executetransaction` module.

If I run`execute_transaction({"a":"b"})` in `executetransaction` module then `transaction` is imported as expected and I get `"in create object"`.

I have added empty `__init__.py` in all folders.

This is my first time posting question here, please tell me if more details are required.

Comment: Does `executetransaction` run properly when not testing or do you get the no module named 'transaction' error?

Comment: @BradenHolt, yes, it runs well without error

Comment: It sounds like a circular import issue but tough to know without seeing more of your code. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744373/circular-or-cyclic-imports-in-python

Comment: Thanks, I have added code to the question. From where I look, I don't seem to import in circular manner, there's import tree for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok your problem is how you import the transaction module in executetransaction.py.

Change `from transaction import Transaction` to `from .transaction import Transaction`. The dot operator tells python that you're wanting to import from the current package.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you [Using local imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53362259/using-local-imports-in-pytest/53362367#53362367)

When importing the package, Python searches through the directories on sys.path looking for the package subdirectory. [docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)